# how to properly get error messages(json) when using devise-angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I am trying to setup devise using angular. I am using angular-devise gem and I made the registration process working. What I can't get to work is displaying devise error messages that are returned from server.

I am successfully getting users.json, but how can I fetch that and show it in view? Below is the JS code which is using the angular-devise method for registration.

There is a `function(error)` line which will get called if there is any errors. I tried to put an alert message there and its getting triggered as expected as well.

But how to fetch the JSON from here?

Below is the JSON response received from the server. I just need to insert this on the view.

**users.json**

```
{ 
  "errors": { 
    "email": ["is invalid"],
    "password":["is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"]
  }
}
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
angular
    .module('checkDevise', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'Devise'])
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            var credentials = {
                email: $scope.user.email,
                password: $scope.user.password,
                password_confirmation: $scope.user.password_confirmation
            };

            var config = {
                headers: {
                    'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'POST'
                }
            };

            Auth.register(credentials, config).then(function(registeredUser) {
                console.log(registeredUser); // => {id: 1, ect: '...'}
            }, function(error) {
                // Registration failed...
                //This actually triggers when there is an error and i think its here to get the json????????

            });

            $scope.$on('devise:new-registration', function(event, user) {
                $scope.user = user;
            });
        };
    });
```

**Update:**

The server is sending the error details as json telling why the user cant be saved(like invalid password or email or already taken email address..)..As suggested by @Rodmentou I added    `$scope.error = RESPONSE_ERROR;` in the error function call and referenced it in the view like {{error}}. Its now displaying the error  in the view exactly as below

the error showing in view now

```
{"data":
  {"errors": 
    {
      "email": ["has already been taken"],
      "password_confirmation":["doesn't match Password"]
    }
  }, 
  "status":422,
  "config": 
    {
      "method":"POST",
      "transformRequest":[null],
      "transformResponse":[null],
      "url":"/users.json",
      "data": 
        {
         "user":          
          {
           "email":"dskfhsiugfs@thing.com", 
           "password":"11111111",
           "password_confirmation":"111111112"}
           },
         "headers": 
           {
             "X-HTTP-Method-Override":"POST",
             "Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*", 
             "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8",
             "X-XSRF-TOKEN":"kxvlsnonsdofsdkfjbsdif"}
           },
        "statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"
       }
```

How can i show only the necessary things only like -  email has already been taken, password dididnt match..??

Got it fixed by adding   $scope.error = RESPONSE_ERROR.data.errors; just if someone needs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            Auth.register(credentials, config).then( 
              function(RESPONSE_SUCCESS) {
                console.log(RESPONSE_SUCCESS); // => {id: 1, ect: '...'}
                $scope.something = RESPONSE_SUCCESS; **//This is how you get it.**
            }, 
              function(RESPONSE_ERROR) {
                //This will only trigger if your server send an error back.
               $scope.error = RESPONSE_ERROR.data.errors;  //This will do the trick
            });
```

After you had assigned $scope.something to RESPONSE_SUCCESS, you can use it on your view as {{something}}. Take a look at [Angular $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) and [Angular $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope);

Comment: why u think there is an error?..I am not getting any errors and its working as expected...as u can see am getting a json response with the expected errors aswell but cant figure out how to show it in controller

Comment: Are you receiving the RESPONSE_SUCCESS? I thought that you were only receiving RESPONSE_ERROR.

Comment: yes am getting succes..i am receving a users.json file with the errors.

Comment: @ABHILASHV.R I've updated my answer. Is this what you want or I haven't understand it yet?

Comment: seems like so..will confirm now.

Comment: actually its showing this "Status Code:422 Unprocessable Entity" . But am getting the json as expected

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes/422_-_Unprocessable_Entity). Can you continue to update your question with info when it comes? I'm kind of in the dark here

Comment: Sorry for the confusion..It worked the way you mentioned. I updated my question. Thanks

Comment: Good that you find your way trough. Congrats. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94494/discussion-between-rodmentou-and-abhilash-v-r).